# What is the #cmakedefine preprocessor directive?

Tags: cmake, c-preprocessor

I am looking through [the source-code for ZeroMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq4-1/blob/master/builds/cmake/platform.hpp.in), which I want to build from source. Inside I found `platform.hpp.in`, which contains:

```
...
#cmakedefine ZMQ_HAVE_SO_PEERCRED
#cmakedefine ZMQ_HAVE_LOCAL_PEERCRED

#cmakedefine ZMQ_HAVE_SOCK_CLOEXEC
#cmakedefine ZMQ_HAVE_SO_KEEPALIVE
#cmakedefine ZMQ_HAVE_TCP_KEEPCNT
...
```

I assume these `cmakedefine` macros are used as templates to generate a header file, but how exactly do they work in CMake? How can I determine what are valid values? How are values set by the user when building the project?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am interested in CMake; ZeroMQ is a motivating example.

Comment: While you could have done some Googling and figured this out, I see no reason for you to get two downvotes, it's a fair "CMake newbie" question. So +1 to balance this out.

Comment: When I done some Googling, this page showed up.  So, thanks for the upvote @einpoklum

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's part of a file that's processed by CMake's [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) command. When `configure_file` is called for the file, `#cmakedefine FOO` is replaced by:

- `#define FOO` - if the CMake variable `FOO` is set to ON or TRUE.
- `/* #undef FOO */` - otherwise.

And that is one way to pass values from CMake into C or C++ source code: The result of `configure_file()` is a C/C++ header file, which is included by the code you want to respect the CMake variable values.